# Interface Builder hang up on retina images

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, retina-display

In my app I create 2 folders for images "Standard" and "Retina" where I put a lot of images for my app. When I open one of my xib file, Interface Builder hang up...

I found that if I remove Retina Image that is used by this xib, then IB will open xib without any problem... This problem occurs only with 1 xib file, another xib files can be opened without any problems. What can be the reason of hang up? Can image be bad? Or maybe I shouldn't put Retina Images to "Retina" folder? What can be the reason?

Thanks...

Comment: What does the debugger show when your app hangs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile and run your application on target you will get a warning on which image is missing. Delete and add that image to your project manually. This should solve your hang issue.

Answer (score 0):

How do you name your retina images? It should be named in the following format: `<your image name>@2x.png`. Second be sure you see these images in the build phase of your target.
As for your xib, that hangs, check that names you use are the same as for non-retina images. IB knows to change these images in run-time with these of retina display. And of course check that you don't use there names of pictures, that you don't have in the project.

Comment: Everything is checked...Everything is fine...100 another images works fine...and xib hang only because of one image...And I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: Try and see in Console application when it hangs, it may shed some light. Check in your project warnings (after you build) whether there is some warning connected to this xib file. If you double click on it it should show you what's wrong. And another question: did you edit it manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "yellow folders" then they are not actual folders. They only serve the purpose of organizing your files in XCode. And second, you should use the normal iPhone image in interface builder and it will automatically locate the @2x image, so if you are using the "blue folders" and separating the images, I think it probably will have a hard time understanding that it should look in "standard" when it is on a non-retina screen and "retina" when it is a retina screen, because you never never told it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You distinguish retina and non-retina images only by their name ending like:
picture.png for normal
picture@2x.png for retina
I usually put them into the same folder so i can easily see what pictures have retina support.

Using [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"] will at first try and load picture@2x.png if your app runs on a device with retina display. If it cannot load the 2x version, it will use the picture.png.